# Populate list using for loop

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

Ok I'm new to programming and this site. I'm using C#. Im trying populate a list using only a for loop. I want the numbers to be 1-5. I've been using the .Add() method but I'm unsure what to put as a parameter for the method. Here's my code so far...

```
List <int> size = new List <int>(5);
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
size[i].Add();
// OR
size[i].Add(i);
```

So do I need to add use Add() or Add(i)? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+list+add ... Since you've already read samples in MSDN ([List.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) ) could you please explain why you show such a strange code and what exactly is not clear in MSDN article?

Comment: Have a look at the MSDN docoumentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I looked at MSDN but I was unsure how to loop the list for each new element. size[0] = 1 then in the next iteration size[1] = 2

Comment: if you want the number to be 1 to 5, your for loop condition should be `int i = 1; i < 6; i++` instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone. One final thing, can anyone tell me why I need to write just size.Add(i) instead of size[i].Add(i)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `size.Add(i)` would work for you. Though it's better to check the MSDN documentation for such things usually :)

Comment: Thank you! Does size.Add(i) still go through each element of size?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you don't need to define the size of the List. It will by dynamic, so you can add as much as you want. It's really only for some optimization that you don't want to bother with.